# Custom URL rewriting in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a very peculiar requirement, hopefully I can explain it without being too confusing.

I created a page template where I list some properties I get from an external XML file, so far no problems, let's say the URL is like this: `http://www.mysite.com/properties/`.

Each property has a link that should redirect the user to a "Single Property" page that displays more info about it.

What I was wondering is if there's a way to make the link like this `http://www.mysite.com/properties/123` where `123` would be the id of the property. Basically if I have the URL like `properties/some_id` I want to be able to load a view file (like the `single.php` or `page.php` files) but specific to this URL condition.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^properties/(\d+)$    single.php?id=$1
```

it will send number(123 in your case) as id to `single.php`